# Oracle's ODP.Net can't handle newlines .Net newlines?

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, odp.net

For a .Net 4.0 application i'm using the OracleClient class from the ODP.Net 11 library. After a bit of research some people note that the ODP.net library can't handle the Windows newlines, but only the unix ones (can't process \r). When I replace every \r occurance with space then query runs fine.

Am I missing something here or is Oracle just being ridiculous?

I'm getting the following error:

```
Message: ORA-06550: line 1, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
The symbol "begin was inserted before "" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 2, column 90:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-id
```

Comment: See here http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Executing-SQL-Scripts-with-OracleODP.aspx

Comment: But it's just a ridiculous oracle thing... I know the workarounds, but it's just that how can oracle make a library and not even support the native environment settings? And for me, i know there just isn't a setting or older version that does work...

Answer (score 4):

The `/r` is not supported by ODP.NET you have to remove it like this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd .CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd .CommandText = commandText.Replace("\r", "");
```

Comment: Yea that much i figured out... But isn't it insane for a .Net library not to support the windows newline character?

Comment: Probally it will developed by Java developers. =)

Comment: Figures... But the main problem is that we were using OleDbConnection and replaced everything with DbConnection. With that change we moved to using native clients SQLConnection and OracleConnection. Query generation we're using StringBuilders with Append and AppendLine for readability in logging. Downside of AppendLine is that it uses Environment.NewLine (\r\n) which the OracleClient doesn't get... I refuse to walk down all the code and replace the \r, because imho this shouldn't be an issue afterall...

Comment: @Ferdy you can derive from OracleCommand and overwrite the CommandText property, so you don't need to change every piece of code.