# Error with ODAC provider with SQL that runs OK in MSDAORA

Tags: sql, oracle, odp.net, odac

If I execute the following SQL on MSDAORA OleDB Provider, it runs OK.

```
BEGIN
MY_PACKAGE_NAME.MY_PROCEDURE_NAME('value1', 'value2');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_NAME as select
     MY_ID ID,
     MY_NAME NAME
from
     MY_OTHER_TABLE';
END;
```

But I'm changing it for Oracle.DataAccess.dll for other reasons, and now I get this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
The symbol "" was ignored.
ORA-06550: line 2, column 52:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-id
ORA-06550: line 8, column 60:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-id
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

.NET code is the following

```vb
Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal sql As String, Optional ByVal parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = Nothing, _
                        Optional ByVal transaction As DbTransaction = Nothing) _
    As Integer Implements IDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery

    Dim cmd As OracleCommand
    Dim result As Integer = -1
    cmd = New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 86400

    Try
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        ex.FillDatabaseExceptionData(cmd)
        Throw
        'Finally
        '    CloseCommand(cmd)
    End Try
    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: Please provide also your .NET code

Comment: thanks, I put the vb.net code. This `OracleCommand` is from namespace `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace \r\n for \n in your command text, because odp.net [does not handle Windows new lines well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306363/oracles-odp-net-cant-handle-newlines-net-newlines)

```
sql = sql.Replace(Environment.NewLine, vbLf)
cmd = New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
```